# type(of:) in combination with generic function crashes on real device

Tags: swift, realm

I am facing some very weird problem getting a function to work from an class which I want to use with Realm. It crashes on a real device, but it does not on a simulator. It crashes on my real device when I use the function below, when directly using `type(of:)`, it doesn't. This is what I mean:

```
import Realm
import RealmSwift

class A: Object {} // It has to inhert from Object to get the problem

// Some class, lets say appDelegate:

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    print(type(of: A())) // Works on both simulator and real device
    testt(typee: A()) // Only works in simulator

}

func testt<T: A>(typee: T) {
    print(type(of: typee)) // EXC_BAD_ACCESS
}
```

I am running iOS 11.0 on my real device and iOS 11.0.1 on the simulator.